# max-width seems to be treated as width; how to wrap around content?

Tags: css, css-grid

I have the following html and css:

```css
.group {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
  grid-gap: 5px;
  outline: 1px solid red;
}
.title {
  grid-column: 1/-1;
}
.booking-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 20px);
  grid-gap: 10px;
  max-width: 150px;  
}
.booking {
  background: green;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="group">
  <h3 class="title">Title 1</h3>
  <div class="name">Name</div>
  <div class="booking-container">
    <div class="booking">1</div>
    <div class="booking">2</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="group">
  <h3 class="title">Title 2</h3>
  <div class="name">Name</div>
  <div class="booking-container">
    <div class="booking">1</div>
    <div class="booking">2</div>
    <div class="booking">3</div>
    <div class="booking">4</div>
    <div class="booking">5</div>
    <div class="booking">6</div>
    <div class="booking">7</div>
    <div class="booking">8</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It seems that the `max-width` is treated as `width`; the first block (Title 1) is wider then neccesary.  What do I do to make it wrap nicely around its content? Is it possible using only css?

Edit: the end result should look like this, but independent of the amount of green blocks (bookings). Hope my question is clear.

```css
    .group {
      display: inline-grid;
      grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
      grid-gap: 5px;
      outline: 1px solid red;
    }
    .title {
      grid-column: 1/-1;
    }
    .booking-container {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 20px);
      grid-gap: 10px;
      max-width: 150px;  
    }
    .booking {
      background: green;
      width: 20px;
      height: 20px;
    }
    
    
    .group1 .booking-container {
      max-width: 70px;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="group group1">
      <h3 class="title">Title 1</h3>
      <div class="name">Name</div>
      <div class="booking-container">
        <div class="booking">1</div>
        <div class="booking">2</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="group">
      <h3 class="title">Title 2</h3>
      <div class="name">Name</div>
      <div class="booking-container">
        <div class="booking">1</div>
        <div class="booking">2</div>
        <div class="booking">3</div>
        <div class="booking">4</div>
        <div class="booking">5</div>
        <div class="booking">6</div>
        <div class="booking">7</div>
        <div class="booking">8</div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method would be to not think of the bookings being in a grid but in a div with max width and displayed as inline blocks.

```css
.group {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
  grid-gap: 5px;
  outline: 1px solid red;
}
.title {
  grid-column: 1/-1;
}
.booking-container {
  max-width: 150px;  
}
.booking {
  background: green;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  display:inline-block;
  margin: 2.5px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
   <div class="group">
  <h3 class="title">Title 1</h3>
  <div class="name">Name</div>
  <div class="booking-container">
    <div class="booking">1</div>
    <div class="booking">2</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="group">
  <h3 class="title">Title 2</h3>
  <div class="name">Name</div>
  <div class="booking-container">
    <div class="booking">1</div>
    <div class="booking">2</div>
    <div class="booking">3</div>
    <div class="booking">4</div>
    <div class="booking">5</div>
    <div class="booking">6</div>
    <div class="booking">7</div>
    <div class="booking">8</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks!! Guess I fell in the 'looking too close for too long'-trap.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really want using grid ? Cause you can have the result you want with basic inline-block (without changing anything in your HTML):

```
.group {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
  outline: 1px solid red;
}
.name{
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top ;
}
.booking-container {
  max-width: 150px;  
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top ;
}
.booking {
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
  background: green;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin:3px;
}
```